# nginx - [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)

Tags: nginx, port

this made me crazy! I want to use nginx on port 81 and apache on 80. apache works correctly but when I want to start nginx I get this error:

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

but I didn't configured any site on port 80 in nginx!

```
server {
    listen       81  default_server;
    listen   [::]:81 default_server  ipv6only=on;
    server_name  _;
    return       444;
}

server {

        listen   81; ## listen for ipv4

        server_name  domain.com;
        root   /home/domain/public_html/;

        location / {

        }

.
.
.
}
```

note that I have not any other file in sites-available an sites-enabled folders.

Comment: Do you have `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`?

Comment: You have an unshown server block with `listen 80` - just delete it. `note that I have not any other file in sites-available an sites-enabled folders.` maybe true - but there _will_ be another server block in the nginx conf listening to 80 and only you can find it.

Answer (score 3):

I found a conf file in `conf.d` folder listening to 80.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep -slir "listen 80" .` to find all files with a common pattern in that directory you are in. Its very helpfull to find such problems if there are some dublicated entries.